# USB-Stick not recognizable by fdisk -l

Tags: linux, usb, usb-drive, fdisk, lsusb

I have a USB-Stick, that does not get properly recognized. In `lsusb` I get the following entry:

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID ffff:1201
```

However in `fdisk -l` I don't see the stick as a option. It is also not recognized by lsblk either.

However, if I look at disks, it somehow got mounted? (See screenshot)

[image]

Don't care about the data but why does it not recognize it anymore and how can I make it recognize it again?

Also, yeah I unplugged it while the stick was busy. Thought that this might happen but anyway, maybe there is a way to save the stick :)

Comment: And what does say `lsblk`? Is it there?

Comment: Does it work on different computer? If you have two same (same manufacturer and model, bought at same time) devices, does the second one work?

Comment: Haven't tested it on a different computer yet but on my windows partition and it also didn't worked over there.

lsblk does not recognize it either. WIll update this in the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

One of possible causes of this behavior is corrupted USB drive firmware. I have one such device (with Chipsbank controller) and it can be hard to recover – the drive essentially stops working and needs reflashing the firmware. Tools for doing that can be usually obtained only from some dubious sources.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think using dubious tools are an option, as the stick was receiving company data. Therefore, I would either prefer to solve it by myself or to destroy the stick also physically. But thanks for the advice ;)